# Is the term "online" used?

Tags: anglais

I know there's the term "en ligne" to mean online. What I'm wondering is, is the term "online" used as well? How commonly?

The context is, I'm buying a domain name for the phrase [french word]-online.fr, and I'm wondering whether to choose [french word]-online.fr or [french word]-enligne.fr. Which sounds better?

Answer (score 2):

The trend is probably still for English sounding names for brands and web sites but that might depend on what "[french word]" is too.

You might also use *xxx-en-ligne.fr*.

Comment: If the first word is unmistakably French, but used mainly within business context (sorry, I can't go into detail here), is it a good idea to combine it with online?

Comment: One ridiculous example: juridiction-online.fr — how does that sound?

Comment: It sounds pretty bad. I would recommend juridiction-en-ligne.fr, juristes-en-ligne, palais-de-justice-en-ligne.fr, and so on.

Comment: One more thing (sorry to bother)—is it alright to omit all hyphens? E.g. juridictionenligne.fr ?

Comment: There is no rule. Sometimes it should be avoided because that gives unintelligible text but that's not the case here.

Answer (score 2):

May be I am wrong but making a quick googling I got the impression that the trend are web adresses of the form that @jlliagre suggests. For instance

[www.academie-en-ligne.fr](http://www.academie-en-ligne.fr)

I did also find some sites without the hyphen (tiret).

Here are is a relative [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=online.fr&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Conline.fr%3B%2Cc0).